Error's while trying to build intel one API Sample's
I'm trying to build Intel one api sample Base_Vector_Add.
i'm getting multiple error as follow's
    In file included from C:\Users\Adithya\source\repos\Base_Vector_Add\src\vector-add-usm.cpp:22:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\sycl.hpp:11:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\accessor.hpp:11:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\access\access.hpp:14:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\CL\__spirv\spirv_ops.hpp:24:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\CL\__spirv\spirv_types.hpp:12:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\half_type.hpp:11:
In file included from C:\PROGRA~2\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\include\sycl\bit_cast.hpp:11:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\type_traits(528,30): error: redefinition of '_Is_memfunptr<_Ret
      (_Arg0::*)(_Types...) __attribute__((fastcall))>'
  528 | _MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF_NOEXCEPT(_IS_MEMFUNPTR)
      | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include\type_traits(451,25): note: expanded from macro '_MEMBER_CALL_CV_REF_NOEXCEPT'

i learnt that this might be due to a conflict between the Intel oneAPI DPC++/C++ Compiler and the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler.
also in intel doc's it has been mentioned that intel oneApi version 2024.1 (which i have installed) is comptable with VS 2022 17.9.2 but I'm using VS 2022 17.9.7 not able to rollback too as it is a community version
how do i fix this or how do i Roll back my Visual studio code.

ok i have modified my question


Open your project in Visual Studio.
Right-click on your project and select "Properties".
Go to "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Command Line", and
add the following compiler option:
/Qnextgen
In "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "General", make sure the
"Platform Toolset" is set to "Intel oneAPI DPC++ Compiler".

